# Comparing bincount and add.at

Tags: numpy

I have 2 questions about how [`np.bincount`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) works and if it is preferred to use over `np.add.at`.

In my small contrived example below, `bincount` and `add_at` will add together interleaved pairs in `x`. This is the same as doing `x[::2] + x[1::2]` (which is much more efficient).

```
x = np.arange(10) # [0, 1, 2, ..., 9]
indices = np.arange(5).repeat(2) # [0, 0, 1, 1, ..., 4, 4]

def bincount(args):
    x, indices = args
    return np.bincount(indices, x, minlength=len(x))

def add_at(args):
    x, indices = args
    out = np.zeros(x.shape, x.dtype)
    np.add.at(out, indices, x)
    return out
```

Visualizing the runtime for both methods using the [`perfplot`](https://pypi.org/project/perfplot/) package:

```
perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: (np.arange(n), np.arange(n//2).repeat(2)),
    kernels=[add_at, bincount],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(3, 12)],
    xlabel='n'
)
```

[image: runtime between bincount and add.at]

It is obvious that `np.bincount` is faster than `np.add.at`. I tried experimenting a bit with changing `indices`, but I was unable to find a case where `np.add.at` is faster than using `np.bincount`.

---

How is `bincount` implemented that makes it so much faster?

The [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) also states that the length of the output is being computed by `np.amax(x)+1`, wouldn't it make sense to be able to specify where the result should be stored when calling `np.bincount` and not have the output length inferred by `np.amax(x)+1`?

Comment: Does it matter how `bincount` is implemented?  It's compiled.  The key difference is that it creates a bin for every value in the range, regardless of whether it occurs in `x`.  So your repeated `arange` is tailor made for it.  It might not be great it you were setting 100 values out of a 10,000 element array.  Think of `bincount` as an abstraction of a `histogram` plot.

Comment: Thanks, what I was trying to get at is if ```bincount``` is always preferred when ```indices``` are of the same size as ```x```. But I think you answered that now with your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found time to investigate this a bit further. The [c-code for `bincount`](https://github.com/numpy/datetime/blob/main/numpy/lib/src/_compiled_base.c#L102) is a straight-forward implementation. It computes the length of the output and then runs the following for-loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    dans[numbers[i]] += weights[i];
}
```

The `weights` is the same as `indices`, but is coerced to a double type and output `dans` is also a double type. I have not looked into the c-code for `np.add.at`, but apparently this for-loop is much faster then doing the unbuffered add.

The speed of `bincount` for large arrays can be increased by using `minlength` as the length of the output instead of [computing](https://github.com/numpy/datetime/blob/main/numpy/lib/src/_compiled_base.c#L126-L127) it.

I added the c-function `np.bincount_fast` which is just a copy of `np.bincount` with the same function body, dispatcher and so on. But instead of computing the min and max, we use the passed `minlength` as the output length. My benchmark now looks like this:

[image]

The double or `np.float64` type casting for the weight also slows down `bincount` and `bincount_fast` a bit.